# Dotted line of moving objects observed on May 5th and May 12th

Tags: star, comets, meteor, satellite, halleys-comet

I saw a dotted line shooting star-like object May 5th and May 12th. It was longer than any meteor/shooting star tail or trail I've ever seen before.  I mean longer in every way, the distance it traveled across the sky, the length of the dotted line and the amount of time I could see it.  I remember somebody from the UK asked the same question 9 months ago..

Comment: Welcome to astronomy SE! First off, you could browse https://www.amsmeteors.org/fireballs/fireball-report/ if you find something there, and if not, please feel free [to report your observation](https://fireball.amsmeteors.org/members/imo/report_intro). You will need the exact location and viewing angle for that (which you did not mention in your question).

Comment: It would be also good if you could link the question you are refering to in your post. I am not sure I remember the same post as you. You could also check https://findstarlink.com/ to see whether you spotted one of the [star link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starlink) [satellite flares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_flare).

Comment: @B--rian I'm not sure if Starlinks actually flare *per se* that often, so I've just asked [Are Starlink satellites flaring?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52149/12102) There certainly are plenty of things that can flare up there, and some could actually blink with LEDs! See [comments](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/43774/#comment89829_43774).